Is affine space the same as a vector space with a vector designated as the origin and a rule for change of origin?
I added the differential geometry tag because that's where I have encountered a useful notion of taking the difference of points locally.
This definition is from Analytical Mechanics by Valter Moretti.

Definition 1.1. A (real) affine space of (finite) dimension $n$ is a set $\mathbb{A}^{n}$, whose elements are called points, equipped with the structures described below.
(1) An $n$-dimensional real vector space $V$ , called space of displacements or space of free vectors.
(2) A map $\mathbb{A}^{n} \times \mathbb{A}^{n} \ni (P,Q) \mapsto (P - Q) \in V$ satisfying the following properties:
(2, i) for any pair $Q\in\mathbb{A}^{n},\; \mathbf{v}\in V$ there is a unique $P \in \mathbb{A}^{n}$ such that $P - Q = \mathbf{v}$;
(2, ii) the identity $P - Q + Q - R = P - R$ holds for any triple $P,Q,R \in \mathbb{A}^{n}$.
If $Q \in \mathbb{A}^{n}$ and $\mathbf{v} \in V$, then $Q + \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{A}^{n}$ denotes the unique point $P$ in $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ such that $P - Q = \mathbf{v}$.
A line in $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ with origin $P$ and tangent vector $\mathbf{u}$ is the map $R \ni t \mapsto P + t\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{A}^{n}$. A segment is obtained from a line by restricting $t$ to some interval different from a point. $\,\diamondsuit$

In what follows the use of the term origin is distinct from that used in the origin of a line.
Proposed alternative definition:
We now define an $n$-dimensional affine space to be a set of points as follows: Given the real $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ we designate a vector $\vec{O} \in V$ to be an origin (point) $O$. A point $P$ is a vector $\vec{P} \in V$ with radial position vector relative to $O$ determined by $\vec{p} = \vec{P} - \vec{O}$.  (Thus $\vec{p} = P - O$ is a vector equation.)
A change of origin $O\mapsto O_*$ means designating a vector $\vec{O}_* \in V$ to be the new origin point $O_*$ with the radial position vectors of points given by $\vec{p}_* = P - O_*$.
A line is defined as Professor Moretti did, with the exception that $\mathbf{u} \neq \mathbf{0}$.
Other than $\mathbf{u} \neq \mathbf{0}$, are these definitions identical?
